# Matlab: modifying array a based on array b

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have two arrays in matlab

```
a = [1 1.1 1.2 1.1 1.3] 
b = [-2 0 1 2 -4]
```

For the negative values in array `b`, example -2 -4, I would like to convert array `a` into negative, -1 and -1.3.

I have used a 'for' loop, which takes too long for 700 000 columns(possibly hours)
looking for a quicker ways to accomplish this. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`a .* sign(b)` works if `b` has no zero elements, `a` can have arbitrary elements.

**Explanation:**

multiply `a` itemwise with the sign of `b`.

**Null fix:**

To fix the null error you can write a function yourself like this (pseudocode):

```
function r = test_sign(b)
if b==0
   r = 1;
else
   r = sign(b);
end
```

Comment: thank you guys for helping me with the solution, i have managed to accomplish what i wanted, in micro-fraction'th' time(that before). really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use logical indexing.

(First I assume `a` and `b` have the same length or your question doesn't make sense).

To get a vector that is `TRUE` when `b` is negative and `FALSE` otherwise, you can just do:

```
b < 0 % depending on what you want, b <= 0
```

You can use this as an index into `a` to grab out those corresponding elements:

```
a( b < 0 )
```

Now that you've selected the right elements make them negative and assign them back:

```
a ( b < 0 ) = - a ( b < 0 );
```

In terms of efficiency, you may want to store the vector `b < 0` to avoid re-calculating it (you'll have to try and see which on you prefer):

```
idx = b < 0;
a(idx) = -a(idx);
```

Matlab is a vectorised language so most times there is a `for` loop, you can avoid it. Read up about this sort of matrix indexing [here](http://www.mathworks.com.au/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html).

Comment: thank you guys for helping me with the solution, i have managed to accomplish what i wanted, in micro-fraction'th' time(that before). really appreciate it.

Comment: Then please accept the answer you used (click the tick on the top-left).